# PreparedStatement / ResultSet and Setters / Getters

Tags: jdbc

I am writing my first Java program (using Struts2) collecting information in 3 fields, writing that information to my db, and then (on the `success.jsp`) displaying all the info from my db in a table.

While I have done a lot of reading about getters / setters and accessing data from / inserting data into a database (in my instance, a MySQL db), one thing isn't clear to me.

In my action class I have `PreparedStatement`s and a `ResultSet` (to write to and pull from the MySQL db):

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO DBName(field1, field2, field3) VALUES(?, ?, ?);");
PreparedStatement pstmtSelect = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM DBName");
{
    pstmt.setString(1, this.field1); 
    pstmt.setString(2, this.field2);
    pstmt.setString(3, this.field3);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();  
    ret = SUCCESS;

    ResultSet rset = pstmtSelect.executeQuery();
    while (rset.next()) {
        field1 = rset.getString(1);
        field2 = rset.getString(2);
        field3 = rset.getString(3);
        ret = SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

My question is: Do I also need the following code in my action class as well or is it redundant? Or does it override the above?

```
public String getField1() {
    return this.field1;
}

public void setField1(String field1) {
    this.field1 = field1;
}

public String getField2() {
    return this.field2;
}
public void setField2(String field2) {
    this.field2 = field2;
}

public String getField3() {
    return this.field3;
}

public void setField3(String field3) {
    this.field3 = field3;
}
```

Comment: (thank you for adding the ognl tag Roman!)

Comment: One more thing about JDBC code better move to the DAO layer instead of mix it with action code. Use the MVC framework via separation the code for different layers.

Comment: Thanks @RomanC - great advice (in Ruby I'd have created separate models, so this makes perfect sense to me).

Comment: whomever downvoted, please comment as to why so I can evolve my method of asking questions in the future. thanks!

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the getters and setter in action class. You just need it in the bean which is holding the 3 fields. In the action class you can create the instance of that bean and call the setter and set the value which you get from the result set. And while displaying you can call the getters to get the value which you just set on the bean.

```
ResultSet rset = pstmtSelect.executeQuery();
            FieldBean field = new FieldBean();         
            while (rset.next()) {
                field.setField1(rset.getString(1));
                field.setField2(rset.getString(2));
                field.setField3(rset.getString(3));
                ret = SUCCESS;
            }
```

Comment: Thank you, @Pratik. Just to be sure I understand your statement "while displaying you can call the getters to get the value which you just set on the bean" 
Do you mean that in the jsp I would set <s:property value="%{FieldBean.field1}"> (one s:property for each field)?

Comment: Since you are using struts you need not call the getters. the framework will do it for you. Yes but you will have to specify one s:property tag for each of the fields